# illegal instructruction interrupt intrinsics on Visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-c++, intrinsics, avx512

I am using visual studio 2022 community edittion and c++. I am using instrinsics caculations. But when I am using this it throws exception:

```
#pragma align(64)
    double a[10] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
    double b[10];
    __m512d m = _mm512_load_pd(&a[0]);
    _mm512_store_pd(&b[0], m);
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Are you using a processor that supports those instructions? My Core i9 does not.

Comment: Try using `alignas(64) double a[10] ...` and `alignas(64) double b[10]`

Comment: Why not write portable C++ and tell your compiler to target a certain CPU or instruction set (and enable optimization)? I'd be surprised if it generates worse code than you do by hand - in fact, I'd generally expect it to do *better*.

Comment: @JesperJuhl clearly you haven't worked on vectorized code very much

Comment: @user253751 Actually I have, and we deleted most of our use of intrinsics a few years ago, since the compilers got good enough that it no longer made sense to keep anything but the generic C++ version. The difference ended up being negligible performance wise, but the maintenance overhead was significant.

Comment: @NathanOliver: MSVC doesn't emit alignment-required instructions, except with legacy SSE when it folds an aligned-load into a memory source operand for an ALU instruction.  Even if you use alignment-required intrinsics, it still uses `vmovdqu` or `vmovupd`, so you can't verify alignment even if you wanted to.  And that would result in a different fault that illegal instruction.

Comment: Illegal instruction faults on AVX-512 are essentially always from running on a CPU without AVX-512.  (Or a VM without it enabled.)  Closing as a duplicate; it can get reopened if the cause is somehow something else.